# Where should I reset match list?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, nlp

I want to loop over a number of files and find the counts of words based on `word.startswith()` in Python3x. There are 3 files: `file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt` each one contains one word which is `for`, i.e., this is only for the sake of demonstration. At the end of execution, I get the output, `for 1`, as if it exists only one time. The output should be `for 3`.

I am sure there is something wrong with defining `match` and resetting it at the end of `if conditions`, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Below is the code:

```
import glob
from collections import Counter
import csv

# Read raw data
list_of_files = glob.glob('*.txt')

# Read locative words, i.e, prepositions
with open("loctives_file.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    locatives = [line.strip() for line in f]

record = []

def locatives_frequency(list_of_files, locatives):
    for file in list_of_files:
        text = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
        lst = text.strip().split()
        del text

        # Define match list
        match = []
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            for locative in locatives:
                if lst[i].startswith('f'):
                    match.append(lst[i])
                    record.append([locative, len(match)])
            match = []

    # Now count the final results
    records = [[k, int(v)] for k, v in record]
    results = Counter(dict(records))

    # Print the frequencies to xlsx file
    with open("freeCounts.xlsx", 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as workbook:
        locatives = csv.writer(workbook, delimiter=',')
        locatives.writerow(["Locative", "Free Count"])

    for k,v in results.items():
        with open("freeCounts.xlsx", 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as workbook:
            locatives = csv.writer(workbook, delimiter=',')
            data = [k, v]
            locatives.writerow(data)

    print("Finished!")

# Call the function
locatives_frequency(list_of_files, locatives)
```

Comment: Aren't you getting erorr - `records` not defined? Can you show with examples what you are trying to do?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Thank you for reply. It was a small typo. I have corrected it. Now there are no lookup errors.

Comment: What is in the locatives file? Can you explain with examples for all the files involved?

Comment: @AnandSKumar the locatives file contains prepositions which I want to get counted. You can make all four files contain only one word which is `for`.

Comment: @AnandSKumar You see that, the final output is an xlsx file containing `for 1` which is not right. I want the output to be `for 3`. I have trouble with `match` variable. It gets cleared improperly. I have tried to change the identation of `match` but it gives either 0 or the `len(match)` multiplied by the number of loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you should directly use a `collections.Counter` , rather than first creating a `match` list, and then adding things to `record` list, etc etc. Which is going wrong in a lot of ways.

Example -

```
def locatives_frequency(list_of_files, locatives):
    results = Counter()
    for file in list_of_files:
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
              text = f.read()
              lst = text.strip().split()
              del text

        for i in range(len(lst)):
            for locative in locatives:
                if lst[i].startswith(locative):
                    results[locative] += 1

    # Print the frequencies to xlsx file
    with open("freeCounts.xlsx", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as workbook:
        locatives = csv.writer(workbook, delimiter=',')
        locatives.writerow(["Locative", "Free Count"])

    for k,v in results.items():
        with open("freeCounts.xlsx", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as workbook:
            locatives = csv.writer(workbook, delimiter=',')
            data = [k, v]
            locatives.writerow(data)

    print("Finished!")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr Anand! Your solution worked and I got the output I was expecting.